# How to fix crispy text in Safari 5 Mac OS X after using css 3d transforms?

Tags: css, safari

I've run into problem when strange behavior is triggered on relative and absolute positioned elements after the element with css 3d transforms applied.

To fix this I have to set background color, but what if I need transparency?

Here is the minimum to reproduce the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/8VABq/3/

Comment: That's weird, for some reason it's removing the anti-aliasing on the text.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug in Safari, I'd recommend submitting a bug report.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall, I've submitted bug report to Safari, but I still hope to find workaround.

Comment: They have fixed this bug in the recent version!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a weird bug indeed.

My first try involved specifying a transparent background color:

```
.crispy {
  position: relative;
  font-size:.9em;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

However, this doesn't work. In fact, if you play with the alpha value (the zero) it seems to range from crispy (0) to normal (1).

Wrapping an inner div and specifying position static doesn't work either.

The only solution I found was this:

```
.crispy {
  position: relative;
  font-size:.9em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

This, however, makes all your text slightly more blurry because it doesn't use the subpixel antialiasing available on LCD monitors. This may (or may not) be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: I marked your answer as acceptable but still it's a compromise. So the best workaround is setting `background-color` if possible, otherwise—setting `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` if transparency is needed.

Comment: The font-smoothing worked reasonably well for me...this is such a gnarly issue, I'm happy with this fix.

Answer (score 3):

I am still experiencing this error in Safari 5.1. What worked for me is to set the font-smoothing myself. Subpixel antialiasing should be the default, but apparently it isn't. If I add the following to the element with broken font rendering, everything looks fine again:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

Comment: I thought it was fixed (jsfiddle example from my question renders just fine). Can you reproduce it with minimum elements?

Comment: Unfortunately jsfiddle has its own problems, but here is an example: https://gist.github.com/2489198. Note that the best solution is to use `-webkit-font-smoothing` *and* a `background-color`. Zoom with ctrl+scroll to see the subtle differences. This problem is very evident with light fonts.

Comment: So it seems that `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` still doesn't work correctly on the relatively positioned elements after element with applied css3dtransform. And the fix that they've done is automatically applying `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` for such elements, that removes crispness but the text renders too thin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hack around to figure out what switches to twiddle to get safari to turn off no-alias mode in transforms. In this case, if you get rid of webkit-perspective or set it to 0px, then the text is rendered non-crispy. You only need webkit-perspective if you'd doing 3D transforms AND actually using the 3rd dimension AND need it.

Comment: I actually need 3D transforms, but in this example I narrowed it down to only `-webkit-perspective` declaration. In real website I have flipping cards inside this div.